# Running "rake test" in production environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I want to run unit tests in a Cron Job in a Production environment. Due to restrictions in the # of machines I have in my disposal, I can only run these units tests in 1 production machine. I don't have a development machine/environment. Let's imagine this is the case (even if it's not a realistic and a bad setup) and I can't change that at all :)

Is it possible to run **"rake test"** or even **"rake test RAILS_ENV=test"** in a production environment? And if I do, would it always run the tests on the test database, not on the production one? And it it does, would the environment be "test" only within the scope of the test?

Obviously, I could test this, but because I don't want to risk production data, I rather have a firm answer before doing this.

Comment: Why would you ever run tests on a cron job? You run tests when your code changes, or when you are about to deploy changed code to production. Does your code change and deploy by a cron job?

Comment: @AlexWayne I need to test several functions that scrape data from websites, as well as call APIS. If the schema for that website or API changes, I need to know. Hence the need for automated tests. Whether they should be unit, or regression or whatever doesn't matter, but the need is there.

Comment: @Hisoka I see. This is a strange use case then, and I would argue one that shouldn't even touch your database, and one entirely separate from your applications main test suite. Usually people go through great lengths to _prevent_ reaching out to remote servers in test suites.  Make a standalone test suite for just this subset of needs, and run just _that_ by a cronjob. Test suites which fail because of things outside of your control seem like a scary thing to maintain.

Comment: @AlexWayne yup, thats doable. So suppose I want to use rake test to test those. Can I do that in prod?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this will work just fine. Make sure you specify the `RAILS_ENV` environment variable like you already have and that you have the test database configured in your `database.yml` file.